# Mirth blank source

Tags: xml, mirth

I'm having trouble with an Web Service Listner channel. If I process the message manually, going to mirth dashboard, clicking on "Send Message" and paste the XML everything works fine.

When I'm trying to use an external application to consume this web service and send the xml, on mirth the message is caught but the source is blank/empty. I've already ensured that the xml is being sent correctly. Is there any option on Mirth that I'm missing?

Comment: very very hard to diagnose your problem with just this much of information. Add snapshot of your source and data type boxes to take it further.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the correct XML Data Type for the channel? If not you can set this in `Channel edit->Source->Set Data Types`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the issue on the Mirth forums.  It turns out it is a Java 8 upgrade issue.  See, http://www.mirthproject.org/community/forums/showthread.php?t=13518